# Button Command is not Working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5, datalist

I am Trying to do

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnItemCommand="DataList2_ItemCommand">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Discription") %>'></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubmittedTime") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" ForeColor="#CC0000" Text="Comments"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton5_Click">Add Comment</asp:LinkButton>
                <br />
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="False" Style="padding-left: 100px;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="40px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="497px"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="Add" CommandName="Add"
                        OnCommand="Button3_Command" />
                </asp:Panel>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and coding for the button3_Click is

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{Button pn = (Button);
    DataListItem dl = (DataListItem)pn.NamingContainer;
    Panel p1 = (Panel)dl.NamingContainer;
    TextBox pan = (TextBox)dl.FindControl("TextBox2");}
```

But button3_Click event is not working. i have applied break point over there but cursor is not coming on break point.

Comment: Check if it debugs into the `oncommand="Button3_Command"`?

Comment: In design view, when you double click on button3, does it take you to the event handling function? (Button3_Click). If no, probably there is some thing wrong with automatic code generated file. Delete it. And debug again. File will be generated and hopefully problem will be solved

Comment: i have already done this but Button3_click event is not working.

Comment: Is your asp file linked to the right code behind file? This section can be found at the top of your asp page with assigns the cs file linked to this page

Comment: can you tell me where is that automatic code generated file in the page or project?

Comment: middelpat: i am using .aspx file and i did not such type of page linked on the top of page.

Comment: `OnCommand="Button3_Command"` - Do you hit this code when you put a breakpoint on? You have an ItemCommand event on the DataList. I would assume that Button3_Command will be hit using a breakpoint.

Comment: it is also not working. i have already done this.

Comment: Move the asp:Panel outside the ItemTemplate tag inside the contentTemplate tag and try again

Comment: but from this i can't add multiple comment on the particular row on data list.

Answer (score 1):

ControlID="Button1" to ControlID="Button3"

Comment: where i can do this. and what controlID

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are able to get into `DataList2_ItemCommand` handler on click of `Button3` button ? If yes, then you should be able to get `CommandName="Add"` in there.